# C++ "Hello world" shows no output

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I installed Codeblocks on my Windows 10 computer. To check that everything works fine, I first compiled the simple C program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

That works without problem but when I try the C++ equivalent:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    return(0);
}
```

Then the "command prompt" window opens but no output is shown. I can see in taskmanager that the program is running but as said without any visible output. I also tried running the program directly from the command line but with the same effect. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Did you create a Console Application project for the C++ code?

Comment: Curious, why the parentheses for `return` in the C++ code but not C?

Comment: @Kup Nothing to do with the question, however.

Comment: @WalterK What happens if you run it in debug mode and [set a breakpoint](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks#Set_Breakpoints) on the first line of `main`?

Comment: You can try this `cout << "Hello World!" << std::flush;`

Comment: @elanius, the manipulator std::endl causes a flush.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.
@NeilButterworth, I did create it as a console application.

Comment: @Kupiakos, unfortunately I am not very familiar with the use of the debugger. I did set a breakpoint on the first line but got the message "tarting the debuggee failed: No symbol table loaded.  Use the "file" command"

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. There was still an older version of MinGW installed in a different folder. I deleted all instances of MinGW, and codeblocks as well. Adter I reinstalled codeblocks everything worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=13484.0) Guy solved similar problem with Codeblocks.

Remove the following Global compiler setting:

```
-Wl,-subsystem,windows
```

Comment: This would only work if that global compiler setting is currently set on their computer. Also, @WalterK, see [here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Global_compiler_variables) for instructions on Global compiler variables.

Comment: @Rama. I looked at my global settings but didn't saw these settings. The compiler settings I currently have are "have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++1]", and "enable all common compiler warnings [-Wall]". No optimizations or CPU architecture tuning options were set.